# How can I extend small-12 (or other similar) class in foundation sites 6?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

How can I extend small-12 (or other similar) class in foundation sites 6 ?

did not manage to extend small-12, also did not find this class in the foundation file? Please advise...

```
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss' ; 

 .form-field {
    @extend .small-12   
}
```

> Error: ".form-field" failed to @extend ".small-12".
>
> ```
>    The selector ".small-12" was not found.
>
>    Use "@extend .small-12 !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
> ```

Comment: Did you verify that the file you're importing actually contains the class you are trying to extend?  You don't get that error for no reason.

Comment: i grepped that whole directory for that class and could not find it. So I am quite puzzled how foundation defines the class as I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

After a little further digging this appears to work...

@import 'settings/_settings.scss';

@import 'foundation';
@include foundation-everything;

.form-field {
    @extend .small-12

}